# When using alternate browsers for an Ionic/Cordova Application, does the app take any dependencies?

Tags: cordova-cli, crosswalk, ionic-cli

This is probably a silly question, but I couldn't find in the documentation.

I need to use the Crosswalk browser for my Ionic/Cordova application. Basically, will my application depend on Chrome or anything else on the Android device for it to run?

Documentation uses the word "embed" so I assume it does not depend on Chrome or other runtime, but I couldn't test it so far. My emulator won't run Android versions below 4.3 (which are exactly the ones I'm targetting).

Answer (score 0):

Crosswalk Runtime is based on Google Chromium, you can explore the official site of Crosswalk https://crosswalk-project.org/ for more info.